# Using trig identities to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Use the identities 
>   $$\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x -1=1-2\sin^2 x$$
>   $$\sin x=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$$
>   to help evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin x} \; dx$$

I've already done $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1+\cos x} , dx$ but I'm stumped on this one, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if $\sin x = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$, then $$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \sin x} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \cos (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x)} \, dx = \int_{u=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \cos u} \, du,$$ the last equality due to the substitution $u = \pi/2 - x$, $du = - dx$.  Now use the same method of solution, namely $\sqrt{1 - \cos u} = \sqrt{2} \sin \frac{u}{2}$, to deduce the result.

Comment: And I was messing around with identities for an eternity when I should've been substituting... Great answer, thank you.

Comment: Did you miss a negative in the last equality?

Comment: @Yeah.. No, because the negative that arises from the substitution is canceled by the change in the direction of integration; namely, $$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \cos (\tfrac{\pi}{2} - x)} \, dx = \int_{u=\pi/2 - 0}^{\pi/2 - \pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \cos u} (-du) = \int_{u=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - \cos u} \, du.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$\sqrt{1-\sin x}=\sqrt{\left(\sin \frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}=\left|\sin \frac{x}{2}-\cos\frac{x}{2}\right|$

Answer (score 0):

Use the expression inside the second identity, $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, as $2x$ in the first identity. This gives you a new expression for the sine

$$
\sin x = 2 \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{x}{2}\right) - 1 = 1 - 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{x}{2}\right).
$$

I will leave it to you to find which of these two expressions will be best suited to simplify the expression inside the integral. You do have to check when you cancel the square root with a square that the function you integrate remains positive of the integration domain.

PS: There are often multiple ways of finding a solution, such as substitution as mentioned in another answer. But it is always good to practice multiple approaches such that you have more tools available to solve more problems in general and this question intended you to practice to rewrite the integral using different trigonometric identities. A related quote would be: ["If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin x} \, dx$

$ = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin x} \, d(x/2)$

$ = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{(\sin x/2 -\cos x/2)^2} \, d(x/2) $

$ = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\sin x/2 -\cos x/2) \, d(x/2)$

that you can further on process taking $ x/2= u $ for substitution.